# How should I handle edit and update action when I use Form Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, object

I have following form object to managing complicated nested form.

**Form**

```
= simple_form_for(@profile_form, :url => profiles_path) do |f|
  ...
```

**Routes**

```
resources :profiles
```

**Controller**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile_form = ProfileForm.new
  end

  def edit
    @profile_form = ProfileForm.new(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @profile_form = ProfileForm.new
    if @profile_form.submit(params[:profile_form])
      redirect_to @profile_form.profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @profile_form = ProfileForm.new(params[:id])
    if @profile_form.submit(params[:profile_form])
      redirect_to @profile_form.profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

**Form Object**

```
class ProfileForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def initialize(profile_id = nil)
    if profile_id
      @profile = Profile.find(profile_id)
      @person = profile.person
    end
  end
  ...
  def submit(params)
    profile.attributes = params.slice(:available_at)
    person.attributes = params.slice(:first_name, :last_name)

    if valid?
      profile.save!
      person.save!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Profile")
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

But right now when I'm editing object using this form `create` action is called.
How should then I refactor this form? Code below on `update` creates another Profile object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simple_form_for` uses `form_for` internally to do its job. `form_for` uses the method `persisted?` to decide if the object is already persisted on the database or not. If it is already persisted `form_for` will generate a form with method *PUT* to update the object, otherwise it will generate a form with method *POST* to create the new object. Therefore you have to implement the `persisted?` method for you form object. You could implement it like this:

```
class ProfileForm
  # ...
  def persisted?
    @person.persisted? && @profile.persisted?
  end
  # ...
end
```

**Update** In the case `@person` is `nil`, i.e. there's no `Person` associated to the `Profile`, I suppose you would create a new `Person` to associate to the `@profile`. In this case it is safe to assume that a `ProfileForm` is `persisted?` as long as at least the `@profile` is `persisted?`, thus:

```
class ProfileForm
  # ...
  def persisted?
    @profile.persisted?
  end
  # ...
end
```

**Update** To avoid the error `` undefined local variable or method `id' `` you have to define the `id` method for `ProfileForm`, like this:

```
class ProfileForm
  # ...
  def id
    @profile.id
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks. But how to change form url then: ``= simple_form_for(@profile_form, :url => profiles_path) do |f|`` And I receive error: ``undefined local variable or method `id' for #<ProfileForm:0x007fe9e7a39070>
``

Comment: And what if @person is nil?

Comment: I still have the same error after added ``to_param`` method. Looks like problem is with url.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace

  = simple_form_for(@profile_form, :url => profiles_path) do |f|

   with

   = simple_form_for(@profile_form, :url => {:controller => "profiles"}) do |f|
```

Comment: No, nothing changed. form url is still: action: ``/profiles`` method: ``post``

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/apply_form_for_options!

You should write method `ProfileForm#persisted?` so that it returns `true` if you want form to update your record.

Comment: I have set up persisted? to ``false``